# spoofing e phishing

Tags: spoofing, phishing

I created a small web application to send emails.

when i send an email Hotmail considers it as spoofing e phishing

how can i sort this problem?

thanks

Comment: You need to provide more information.  E.g.: What's the From address you're using?  Is SPF set up on your from address?  How many e-mails are you sending?  What's the content of the e-mails?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.interspire.com/content/articles/6/1/Avoiding-the-Spam-Filters-and-Other-Email-Marketing-Tips

> The right selection of words Many spam
>   filters work by analyzing the email
>   based on its content and the words
>   used. Many words -- such as free, sex
>   and so forth -- are very heavy spam
>   trigger keywords. Your priority should
>   be to avoid such words while keeping
>   your newsletter as professional as
>   possible.
>
> Later in this article I will show you
>   a technique that I use to help me
>   detect words that could trigger spam
>   filters that I may have missed.
>
> Pay attention to your formatting When
>   formatting your email, keep it simple
>   and professional. Excessive use of
>   different colors, fonts, sizes, images
>   and so forth will result in a higher
>   spam filtering rate. Keep your email
>   as clean as possible, and try to stick
>   to a maximum of 2 or 3 different font
>   types and sizes. Overly large sized
>   fonts will surely add to an email
>   being flagged as spam, as will too
>   many images (or not enough text).
>
> Try and use a short and simple
>   stylesheet rather than using font tags
>   excessively. Most spam filters don't
>   appreciate a multitude of font tags
>   and inline formatting, and the more
>   primitive filters can't detect
>   stylesheets so they will not penalize
>   as easily.
>
> Consistency is king Use a template if
>   you plan on sending newsletters
>   consistently. This will make sure that
>   all your newsletters look and feel the
>   same. It will also add a touch of
>   professionalism and branding to your
>   newsletters.
>
> Whilst not directly affecting spam
>   filters, this will enable your readers
>   to distinguish your newsletter
>   instantly, thus not reporting it as
>   spam accidentally. Some spam filters
>   work by querying a spam server,
>   whereas others report individual
>   emails as spam. If your email gets
>   reported as spam, then more than
>   likely multiple spam filters will flag
>   your email.
>
> Being consistent with your timing of
>   the newsletter also helps. For
>   example, if you send a newsletter once
>   per month (I personally don't
>   recommend you send out any more than
>   this, unless you've got something
>   really interesting to say), then aim
>   to send it out at the same time, on
>   the same day each month.
>
> Once again, your potential readers
>   will learn to expect your email,
>   adding professionalism and often
>   improving open rates, also reducing
>   accidental spam flagging as well.
>
> Always use Double Opt-in Always make
>   your mailing lists double opt-in. This
>   means that when a user subscribes to
>   your mailing list, they will be sent
>   an email with a link that they must
>   click on to confirm their
>   subscription.
>
> This is very important because many
>   people can accidentally enter an
>   incorrect email address, or even the
>   email address of someone else on
>   purpose. When that person receives a
>   newsletter they did not subscribe to,
>   they will assume they have been
>   spammed, and your newsletter (and
>   possibly your web server) will be
>   reported as spam.
>
> Unsubscribe and Contact Information
>   Every newsletter you send out should
>   contain a way for the reader to
>   unsubscribe. Not doing so is illegal
>   in some countries and is an instant
>   sign of spamming. You should also
>   display your contact information
>   (Phone, Fax and Address) clearly, as
>   this greatly increases confidence in
>   your email and your company, as well
>   as conforms to spam laws in the United
>   States. Contact information also
>   allows a potential customer to contact
>   you if need be.

Comment: Good points.  I'd also add: In the UK, you must add your company registration number to your e-mails (if you are a company).  This is a legal requirement on all official company e-mails, not just mailing lists.

Answer (score 0):

This commonly occurs when you programatically send an email from an address that doesn't actually exist. It can also be down to the IP address of the server being black-listed - so if you're on shared hosting and someone is spamming from it on a different account, for example.

Comment: This may be one problem as i am on a shared server.

I was just sending the email from myself to myself and still getting the same result.

the email content was just a couple of text.

thanks guys for your help!